# Alternative of slower ifelse in R data table

Tags: r, performance, if-statement, data.table

I am writing a function where multiple ifelse are being used for data table operation. Although I am using data tables for speed but multiple ifelse making my code slow and this function is for large data set. Hence I was wondering if there is an alternative to iflese.
One example iflese from the function(there are close to 15 iflese ), in this example flag is set to 1 if x is blank else 0.

```
    dt<-dt[,flag:=ifelse(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x),1,0)]
```

Comment: Doing `dt <- dt` is also making it slower. Why are you doing it if you are already using `:=`? You could also avoid `ifelse` here by simply doing something like `dt[is.na(x)|!nzchar(x), flag := 1]` (though instead of `0` you will have `NA` which is very easy to manipulate using `is.na` if needed)

Comment: Try `dt[,flag:= as.integer(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x))]` instead

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for your prompt response, as I am new to R and Data table both I was not aware of that. Is there any other way where we can write ifelse like statement.?

Comment: You don't need `ifelse` here. Either try my suggestion or @docendodiscimuss. Mine will be probably faster, while his will match your desired output better. Also, please read [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) in order to understand how `:=` works.

Comment: You could also `add` `0L` and coerce it to integer ie. `dt[, flag:= (is.na(x)|!nzchar(x))+0L]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg , I am also using this in the code impute_info2[,value:=ifelse(varname==eval(imputevar),'user defined',type)]    ...can it be transformed in a way as you suggested before?

Comment: You can do it in two quick steps. For example. `impute_info2[,value:="type"] ; impute_info2[varname==eval(imputevar), value:="user defined"]` or something similar. Another way is to use simple indexing, for example `impute_info2[,value:=c('type', 'user defined')[(varname==eval(imputevar)) + 1L]]` (though it's hard for me to test the code without the actual data, but you get the idea).

Comment: @akrun If you want to code-golf it try `+(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x))`. Fewer characters, faster, and also gives an integer. Speed comparison: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23991793#23991793

Comment: @Frank Thanks for that `+`.  I have to update my code-golf notes with this.

Comment: @akrun Okay, done. For this question, I think exploiting the fact that only `c(NA_character_,"")` meet the condition for the flag gives the fastest solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest approach will probably depend on what your data looks like. Those mentioned in the comments are all comparable for this example:

(`twice` was mentioned by @DavidArenburg; and `onceadd` by @akrun. I'm not really sure how to benchmark these with `replications` > 1, since the objects are actually modified during the benchmark.)

```
DT <- data.table(x=sample(c(NA,"",letters),1e8,replace=TRUE))

DT0 <- copy(DT)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)
DT4 <- copy(DT)
DT5 <- copy(DT)
DT6 <- copy(DT)
DT7 <- copy(DT)

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
ifelse  = DT0[,flag:=ifelse(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x),1L,0L)],
keyit   = {
    setkey(DT1,x)   
    DT1[,flag:=0L]
    DT1[J(NA_character_,""),flag:=1L]
},
twiceby = DT2[, flag:= 0L][is.na(x)|!nzchar(x), flag:= 1L,by=x],
twice   = DT3[, flag:= 0L][is.na(x)|!nzchar(x), flag:= 1L],
onceby  = DT4[, flag:= +(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x)), by=x],
once    = DT5[, flag:= +(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x))],
onceadd = DT6[, flag:= (is.na(x)|!nzchar(x))+0L],
oncebyk = {setkey(DT7,x); DT7[, flag:= +(is.na(x)|!nzchar(x)), by=x]},
replications=1
)[1:5]
#      test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 1  ifelse            1   19.61   31.127     17.32
# 2   keyit            1    0.63    1.000      0.47
# 6    once            1    3.26    5.175      2.68
# 7 onceadd            1    3.24    5.143      2.88
# 5  onceby            1    1.81    2.873      1.75
# 8 oncebyk            1    0.91    1.444      0.82
# 4   twice            1    3.17    5.032      2.79
# 3 twiceby            1    3.45    5.476      3.16
```

*Discussion*. In this example, `keyit` is the fastest. However, it's also the most verbose and it changes the sorting of your table. Also, `keyit` is very specific to the OP's question (taking advantage of the fact that exactly two character values fit the condition `is.na(x)|!nzchar(x)`), and so might not be as great for other applications, where it would need to be written something like

```
keyit   = {
    setkey(DT1,x)
    flagem = DT1[,some_other_condition(x),by=x][(V1)]$x
    DT1[,flag:=0L]
    DT1[J(flagem),flag:=1L]
}
```

Comment: I think `dt[is.na(x)|!nzchar(x), flag := 1]` is also relevant as having `NA`s  instead of `0`s should be fine in most cases.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Okay, I tried that.  It comes in at 4.2x `keyit`, about the same as `twice`.

Comment: Hmm... Strange. I don't know about your benchmarks though. How come `onceby` is two times faster than `once`?

Comment: @Frank re benchmarking and multiple replications - you could add `copy(DT)` to all of the functions (instead of using `DT1`, `DT2`, etc) - that won't affect relative comparisons

Comment: @eddi Good idea. It's monstrously slow.

Comment: Adding `copy(DT)` would make the ratios (in the `relative` column) less meaningful, but that's a good idea, too. I might do that next time.

Comment: @Frank fair enough - then just remove the column at the end of each computation - that should have a much smaller effect on those ratios; or use `copy(DT)` and absolute values and additionally benchmark `copy(DT)` itself

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1232) for some advice I got from Jan about how to run benchmarks when pesky copies are unavoidable and you don't want to ruin the ratios. Basically gonna require a lot more labor...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Ouch, making a new copy in each loop and losing all those nice `microbenchmark` summary columns. Okay, thanks.

Comment: Yea, pretty painful, but... for science!