# conditional data.table match for subset of data.table

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, match

This post is related to the previous post here: [match rows of two data.tables to fill subset of a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320621/match-rows-of-two-data-tables-to-fill-subset-of-a-data-table)

Not sure how I can integrate them together.
I have a situation where other than the NA for one column of DT1, a couple of more conditions should apply for merging, but that doesn't work.

```
> DT1 <- data.table(colA = c(1,1, 2,2,2,3,3), colB = c('A', NA, 'AA', 'B', NA, 'A', 'C'), timeA = c(2,4,3,4,6,1,4))
> DT1
   colA colB timeA
1:    1    A     2
2:    1 <NA>     4
3:    2   AA     3
4:    2    B     4
5:    2 <NA>     6
6:    3    A     1
7:    3    C     4
> DT2 <- data.table(colC = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), timeB1 = c(1,3,6, 2,4, 1), timeB2 = c(2,5,7,3,5,4), colD = c('Z', 'YY', 'AB', 'JJ', 'F', 'RR'))
> DT2
   colC timeB1 timeB2 colD
1:    1      1      2    Z
2:    1      3      5   YY
3:    1      6      7   AB
4:    2      2      3   JJ
5:    2      4      5    F
6:    3      1      4   RR
```

Using the same guideline as mentioned above, I'd like to merge ColD of DT2 to colB of DT1 only for NA values of colB in DT1 AND use the values of colD for which timeA in DT1 is between timeB1 and timeB2 in DT2. I tried the following but merge doesn't happen:

```
 > output <- DT1[DT2, on = .(colA = colC), colB := ifelse(is.na(x.colB) & i.timeB1 <= x.timeA & x.timeA <= i.timeB2, i.colD, x.colB)]
> output
> output
   colA colB timeA
1:    1    A     2
2:    1 <NA>     4
3:    2   AA     3
4:    2    B     4
5:    2 <NA>     6
6:    3    A     1
7:    3    C     4
```

Nothing changes in output.
these is my desired output:

```
> desired_output
   colA colB timeA
1:    1    A     2
2:    1   YY     4   --> should find a match
3:    2   AA     3
4:    2    B     4
5:    2 <NA>     6   --> shouldn't find a match
6:    3    A     1
7:    3    C     4
```

why doesn't this work?
I'd like to use data.table operations only without using additional packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An in place update of the `colB` in `DT1` would work as follows:

```
DT1[is.na(colB), colB := DT2[DT1[is.na(colB)], 
                    on = .(colC = colA, timeB1 <= timeA, timeB2 >= timeA), colD]]
print(DT1)
   colA colB timeA
1:    1    A     2
2:    1   YY     4
3:    2   AA     3
4:    2    B     4
5:    2 <NA>     6
6:    3    A     1
7:    3    C     4
```

This indexes the values where `colB` is `NA` and after a join on the condition, as defined in `on= ...`, replaces the missing values by the matching values found in `colD`.

Comment: thanks so much for your solution. the condition for timeA is not to be the same as timeB1, but rather timeB1 <= timeA <= timeB2. I changed the data.table data so it becomes more clear.

Comment: Nice answer. `DT2[DT1[is.na(colB)], ...` could be `DT2[.SD, ...`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the sortest answer, but it gets the job done.. I'm no data.table-expert, so I welcome improvements/suggestions.

```
DT1[ is.na(colB), colB := DT1[ is.na(colB), ][ DT2, colB := i.colD, on = c( "colA == colC", "timeA >= timeB1", "timeA <= timeB2")]$colB]
```

what is does:
first, subset DT1  for all rows where is.na(colB) = TRUE
then, update the value of colB in these rows with the colB-vector  from the result of a non-equi join of the same subset of rows on DT2

Bonus is that DT1 is chaged by reference, so it's pretty fast and memory efficient on large data (I think).

```
   colA colB timeA
1:    1    A     2
2:    1   YY     4
3:    2   AA     3
4:    2    B     4
5:    2 <NA>     6
6:    3    A     1
7:    3    C     4
```

Comment: I see what is happening in your solution, thanks so much!! I still don't understand why my solution didn't work though...